# HBase binding to an incorrect address

Tags: hadoop, bind, hbase

I'm attempting to run running HBase in pseudo-distributed mode. I have followed all of the steps in the tutorial.

My **hbase-site.xml** looks like this:

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>1</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

My **regionservers** looks like this (default):

```
localhost
```

In the logs, Zookeeper starts OK, MiniZK starts OK, then I get a **BindException** with this being the culprit:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to /192.168.0.1:0 : Cannot assign requested address
```

Where in the world did it get the address **192.168.0.1**?  And why is it trying to bind to port 0?  That IP is my NAT gateway.  The IP address of the machine it's on is **192.168.0.200**.

I have looked in all of the config files but don't see anywhere that I would specify that address.

** UPDATE **

It looks like the problem was that HBase was trying to reverse-lookup my IP address by my hostname which-- because I'm using my router as a DNS-- resolved to ... my router.

When I add an "alias" in the **/etc/hosts** file to 127.0.0.1 it resolves just fine.

@arnon-rotem-gal-oz, I just installed whatever came in the HBase tarball. I'm assuming miniZK is a scaled-down version of Zookeeper?  I'm not running a separate instance of it.

The code you posted did the trick to resolve the **next** problem that came up.

Comment: Is there something funky in your /etc/hosts?

Comment: I thought that, too, but:

`127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
::1  localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6`

(sorry it's mashed together-- doesn't let me markup)

Answer (score 0):

Check the zookeeper configuration file (zoo.cfg in the zookeeper/conf directory)
Also why do you have both zookeeper and miniZK?

Also (not directly related to your question) you need to tell hbase where to find the zookeeper e.g. adding the following to your hbase-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

just fix all dir issues because if hbase fail to start it will be try to connect from strange IPs.

1. add to bin folder winutils.exe
2. correct path's
3. this is not a IP issue is a wrong dirs issues

> ```
>  hbase-env.cmd
>  set HBASE_CLASSPATH=%HBASE_HOME%\lib\client-facing-thirdparty\*
>  @rem my hbase in in bin bin so bin is main dir
>  set HADOOP_HOME=M:\Hbase\bin\
> ```

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/M:/Hbase/zookeeper/</value>   </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:/M:/Hbase/HFiles</value>   </property>


  <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>    </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.master.ipc.address</name>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>    </property>
       <property>
      <name>hbase.master.hostname</name>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>    </property>

   <property>
      <name>hbase.regionserver.hostname</name>
      <value>127.0.0.1</value>    </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.ipc.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>   </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.home.dir</name>
    <value>/M:\Hbase\bin\bin</value>   </property>
```